# Plotly Express Choropleth Map Animation loading extremely long

Tags: python, dictionary, plotly, geojson, choropleth

I am making an animated choropleth map of regions in Czechia. When I run it without the animation, purely on one set of the data it takes 7.5 seconds. Here is the code for that.
[image]

However when I tried making the animation I had to stop it after 16 hours without a solution. And the HTML file I was saving it in got almost to 1GB in size. Here is the code I use for the animation.

```
fig = px.choropleth(df_anim,
             locations=REGION_CODE_COL,
             featureidkey=f"properties.{REGION_CODE_COL}",
             geojson=regions_json,
             color=REL_RANGE_TEXT,
             hover_name=REGION_NAME_COL,
             hover_data={
                 REGION_CODE_COL: False, 
                 REGION_NAME_COL: False, 
                 TIME_COL_NAME: False, 
                 REL_COL_NAME: False, 
                 REL_RANGE_TEXT: False,
                 REL_TEXT_COL: True
             },
             color_discrete_map=dict(zip(INTERVAL, COLOR)),
             category_orders={
                  REL_RANGE_TEXT : INTERVAL
              },
             animation_frame=TIME_COL_NAME,
             projection="orthographic"
                   )
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons[0].args[1]['frame']['duration'] = 1000
fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons[0].args[1]['transition']['duration'] = 200
# fig.write_html(OUTPUT_HTML_FILE_NAME)
fig.show()
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to optimize this program I would really appreciate it. The main thing I don’t understand is why REL1506 which is data for year 2015 month 6 takes only 7.5 seconds to load but the animation over 12 months couldn’t finish in 1000minutes (I let it on overnight). I stripped the dataframe and the geojson to only the bare minimum needed for the animation which took the HTML filesize down by about 30% but still wasn’t enough.

Larger regions geojson (1MB), dataframe (2500 rows), animation + HTML file saved (1 minute)
Smaller regions geojson (9MB), dataframe (75000 rows), animation + HTML file saved (couldn’t do it in 1000minutes and the HTML file appeared in my folder after about 6 minutes)

Comment: I don't think I have extensive experience yet, but my advice is that from a plotly perspective, the larger the saved HTML file, the more data it holds on the page itself. From a visualization perspective, the granularity of the visualization is too fine. I recommend that you try to visualize in larger administrative units.

Comment: I know that the granularity is too fine, but I already made it in 2 types of larger regions and I need this one also. Is there a possibility to embed plotly python code in a js website so that I don't need to export the animation in HTML, and that I will just add the geojson and excel source files in the same folder as will be the website?

Comment: Exporting to a webpage, as ploty does, has its limits performance-wise. Perhaps you can make the operations a bit lighter using the `Simplify` method provided by GeoPandas or Shapely. It reduces the number of edges used to render the map. This makes it less detailed, but you can stick with the units you are using.